# How can I put a timer in my game?

Tags: timer, coronasdk, scoring

I have been trying to make a score keeper for my game in Corona SDK, but to no avail.  How can I make a score keeper that adds one every second then saves the high score?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Corona SDK, how can I put a timer in my game?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267102/in-corona-sdk-how-can-i-put-a-timer-in-my-game)

Comment: Yea noons was answering the other one so I asked again

Comment: Frozire, im really having trouble with the timer so if you could help that would be awesome.  Since,  I noticed,  you're basically the only person who helps me on this forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I normally don't just give solutions like this, for the future try to break your problem into smaller problems. Start with, how can I show text on my screen? Then go for, how can I update the text on my screen? And then start looking for ways to update every second. etc. Makes it a lot easier.

```
-- Variables
local score = 0
local scoreTxt = display.newText( "Score: "..score, 100, 200, native.systemFont, 16 )
scoreTxt:setFillColor( 1, 0, 0 )

-- Listener for your timer, updates score variable and updates the text
local function scoreKeeper( event )
    score = score + 1
    scoreTxt.text = "Score: "..score
end

-- Timer
timer.performWithDelay( 1000, scoreKeeper, -1 )
```